# Why won't my captcha show up on my site when I do this?

Tags: asp.net

I put the captcha here, yet it doesn't wanna show up on the site if I put it here. I'm trying to figure out how to add captcha to my site for sign up, as someone spammed 200K accounts on my site.

Tried putting it here, expected it to work. Didn't work.

```
<button id="signup-button" type="button" tabindex="9" class="btn-primary-md signup-submit-button" rbx-form-interaction name="signupSubmit" ng-disabled="isSubmitting" ng-show="isSectionShown" data-signup-api-url="/api/v1/users/signup" ng-click="submitSignup($event)" ng-keypress="submitSignup($event)">Sign Up is currently disabled.</button>
<noscript>
    <div class="cf-turnstile" data-sitekey="0x4AAAAAAAHPwkYFIYuGlOhU" data-theme="dark" data-callback="javascriptCallback"> </div>
    <div class="text-danger">
        <strong>JavaScript is required to submit this form.</strong>
    </div>
</noscript>
```